# Scrolling to an HTML Element in a Scrollable DIV from an AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am hoping that someone has seen this issue before and that you may have a solution.

I have a function that is called when my controller loads that should scroll an HTML element (happens to be a div element) to the top of a containing div that is scrollable.  The HTML for the page is in a view that is loaded when the user navigates to the route associated with it, and the div to be scrolled to is created in an ng-repeat.

The scroll function works perfectly when called from a click function in a user interaction with the page after the controller and the view are loaded.  The function is:

```
// scrolls the specified html element into view
function scrollToElementByID(id) {
    // locate the html element to scroll to
    var 
        elem = document.getElementById(question.divID);

    // found the element associated with the question - set focus on it
    if (elem) {
        // get the position of the top of the element
        var 
            topPos = elem.offsetTop;

        // get the div in which the element is located
        var 
            elemParent = elem.parentNode;

        // scroll the containing div to the element position
        elemParent.scrollTop = topPos;

    }
}
```

However, the function does not work when first called from an initialization function that is called when the controller first loads.  The getElementById function call returns null, which seems like it is indicating that the html element has not been created at the time of the call.

I have tried using the $viewContentLoaded event, but that fires long before the scroll call and it still fails, and setting a $timeout and an $interval did not work either.  Anybody have a suggestion as to how I can scroll my scrollable div to a specified element when the user navigates to the route?

Thanks!

**Further info based on Fedaykin's comment:**

I modified your controller code to try to demonstrate what I need.  Your sample directive works well when the user interacts with the page after it is loaded, as in your plunkr, but I need the scroll to occur automatically like this (see the comments marked CHANGE):

```
app.controller( 'myCtrl', [ '$scope', '$routeParams', function ( $scope, $routeParams ){

  $scope.value = 'test';
  $scope.itemsOne = [];
  $scope.itemsTwo = [];

  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    $scope.itemsOne.push(makeSentence());
    $scope.itemsTwo.push(makeSentence());
  }

  // CHANGE: get the row and column from query string params
  var
    row = $routeParams.r,
    col = $routeParams.c;

// CHANGE: controller initialization function - called when controller loads
function init() {
    // scroll to requested row in requested column
    $scope.scrollToMe(row, col);
}

// CHANGE: call controller initialization
init();

  function makeSentence() {
    var text = ""; 
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < Math.random() * 200; i++ ){
      for( var i=0; i < Math.random() * possible.length; i++ )
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      text += " ";
    }
    //console.log(text);
    return text;
  }

  $scope.scrollMeTo = function(column, row){
    // scroll me to an area in a column
    if(column == 1)
      $scope.itemColumn1 = row;

    if(column == 2)
      $scope.itemColumn2 = row;
  };

}] );
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle? thx

Comment: A plunkr would definitely help a lot, other day I built this to solve a scrolling question, maybe it can be helpful to you: http://plnkr.co/edit/2gb8ZdZ5DPanRBVQvTwa

Comment: Thx, Fedaykin.  I like your auto-scroll-to directive -- good idea.  I tried to incorporate it in my page, and it works just as I'd expect when the user interacts with the page in the browser.  However, it does not do anything when the view loads.  Not sure how I'd make a plunkr of what I need - don't use it much and I'd need to read query string values when the page loads.  See my updates to your controller code below for an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.